# php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.21-1) but it is not installable

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt-get

I went to install php5-curl, I sadly did not read that it would remove php5-mysql. I really need that, so when I go to install it apt-get says

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.21-1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.2

Can anyone help?

EDIT:
Well, apt-get still cant find it, but I manually downloaded the deb (here http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-dfsg-5.1/libmysqlclient16_5.1.69-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_amd64.deb) and installed it now it works fine

Comment: Well congratulations on getting it working!

Comment: It is good to see that you've finally cracked the problem, Please tell me how you ended up, So that I can get an easy solution just like you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing problems regarding Broken packages then first of all remove that package by first checking dependencies and then forcefully remove that package, and don't ever forget to reboot when you do make enormous changes in your system. To remove that package use these shell commands
First be a super user : login through root

```
$ sudo su
```

Then Enter your password

```
# apt-cache rdepends package-name
# apt-get --purge remove --force package-name
```

Then reboot your system and put these shell commands

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get autoclean
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

and When you are done try re installing your desired package with

```
# apt-get install package-name
```

This worked in my Ubuntu, Try this, I believe this will fix all your problems, Good luck.

Comment: Well As you can see in my edits, I no longer have the issue, but I believe this would have fixed it

Comment: Congrats, @JonathanSchoberJr.